# How to differentiate the ID number color of table row with the selected value in dropdown?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, selectonemenu, conditional-rendering

I am new to JSF and i suppose to finish one task.
The aim of the task is display ID number background color with selected value of drop-down list.
I have created a drop-down list and wrote code to display and to store value in database.

Drop-down list code is:

```
                     <h:panelGrid>
                        <h:outputText value="Télémétré:" styleClass="reqStyle" style="margin-left:20px;" />
                            <h:selectOneMenu value="#{dossierBean.dossier.telemetre}">
                                <f:selectItem  itemValue="OUI:Fournisseur ISA" itemLabel="OUI:Fournisseur ISA" />
                                 <f:selectItem itemValue="OUI:Fournisseur Silicon Controls/Gaslog" itemLabel="OUI:Fournisseur Silicon Controls/Gaslog" />
                                 <f:selectItem itemValue="NON Telemetre" itemLabel="NON Télémétré" />
                            </h:selectOneMenu>
                     </h:panelGrid>
```

Here i have written code to display selected value.
I displayed logo instead of selected value..

```
<h:graphicImage url="resources/image/blue.jpg" title="OUI:Fournisseur ISA" rendered="#{dossierBean.dossier.telemetre == 'OUI:Fournisseur ISA'}" />
<h:graphicImage url="resources/image/green.jpg" title="OUI:Fournisseur Silicon Controls/Gaslog" rendered="#{dossierBean.dossier.telemetre == 'OUI:Fournisseur Silicon Controls/Gaslog'}" />
```

The saved file(row) information of code is:

```
<p:column sortBy="#{dossier.id}" width="50" filterBy="#{dossier.id}" style="text-align:center;" filterStyle="width:40px;font-size:10px;">
                            <f:facet name="header">No</f:facet>
                            <h:commandLink action="#{taskBean.showDossier(dossier)}" value="#{dossier.id}" title="Visualiser" styleClass="#{dossier.dui.style}"  style="font-weight:bold;"/>
```

I don't understand but some how already all ID background color display with selected class name:

```
.urgentPriority {color:red!important; font-size:11px;}
.alertPriority {color:orange!important; font-size: 10px;}
.normalPriority {color:green!important; font-size: 10px;}
.endPriority {color:#aaaaaa!important; font-size: 10px;}
.codeTask {color:#aaaaaa; font-size: 24px; font-weight: bold;}
```

[I want to display out put like in screenshot.. first selected value should display in red color second selected value should display in green color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ruw9U.png)

Any suggestion please?